# Declare reference member variable that you won't have at instantiation

Tags: c++, class, constructor, reference

Coming from Java, C++ is breaking my brain.

I need a class to hold a reference to a variable that's defined in the main scope because I need to modify that variable, but I won't be able to instantiate that class until some inner loop, and I also won't have the reference until then. This causes no end of challenges to my Java brain:

1. I'm used to declaring a variable to establish its scope, well in advance of knowing the actual value that will go in that variable. For example, creating a variable that will hold an object in my main scope like `MyClass test;` but C++ can't abide a vacuum and will use the default constructor to actually instantiate it right then and there.
2. Further, given that I want to pass a reference later on to that object (class), if I want the reference to be held as a member variable, it seems that the member variable must be initialized when it's declared. I can't just declare the member variable in my class definition and then use some `MyClass::init(int &myreference){}` later on to assign the reference when I'll have it in my program flow.

So this makes what I want to do seemingly impossible - pass a reference to a variable to be held as a member variable in the class at any other time than instantiation of that class. [UPDATE, in `stack-overflow-rubber-ducking` I realized that in this case I CAN actually know those variables ahead of time so can side-step all this mess. But the question I think is still pertinent as I'm sure I'll run into this pattern often]

Do I have no choice but to use pointers for this? Is there some obvious technique that my hours of Google-fu have been unable to unearth?

TLDR; - how to properly use references in class member variables when you can't define them at instantiation / constructor (ie: list initialization)?

Comment: Show some code, don't describe it in prose. Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: Without example code it is hard to tell what the correct solution should be, but in C++ you need to manage lifetime of your objects yourself. If a class should hold a (non-owning) reference to another object, the class instance's lifetime shouldn't exceed that of the referenced object. For owning "references" there is e.g. `std::unique_ptr` which can be default-initialized. For reassignable references, there are pointers and `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: Your problem comes from terminology. What is called a reference in Java is **NOT** the same thing as a C++ reference. A Java reference is much closer to a C++ pointer (or std::shared_ptr as they delete when all references are gone).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Declare reference member variable that you won't have at instantiation

All references must be initialised. If you don't have anything to initialise it to, then you cannot have a reference.

The type that you seem to be looking for is a pointer. Like references, pointers are a form of indirection but unlike references, pointers can be default initialised, and they have a null state, and can made to point to an object after their initialisation.

Important note: Unlike Java references, C++ references and pointers do not generally extend the lifetime of the object that they refer to. It's very easy to unknowingly keep referring to an object outside of its lifetime, and attempting to access through such invalid reference will result in undefined behaviour. As such, if you do store a reference or a pointer to an object (that was provided as an argument) in a member, then you should make that absolutely clear to the caller who provides the object, so that they can ensure the correct lifetime. For example, you could name the class as something like `reference_wrapper` (which incidentally is a class that exists in the standard library).

In order to have semantics similar to Java references, you need to have shared ownership such that each owner extends the lifetime of the referred object. In C++, that  can be achieved with a shared pointer (`std::shared_ptr`).

Note however, that it's generally best to not think in Java, and translate your Java thoughts into C++, but it's better to rather learn to think in C++. Shared ownership is convenient, but it has a cost and you have to consider whether you can afford it. A Java programmer must "unlearn" Java before they can write good C++. You can also subsitatute C++ and Java with most other programming languages and same will apply.

> it seems that the member variable must be initialized when it's declared.

Member variables aren't directly initialised when they are declared. If you provide an initialiser in a member declaration, that is a default member initialiser which will be used if you don't provide an initialiser for that member in the member initialiser list of a constructor.

You can initialise a member reference to refer to an object provided as an argument in a (member initialiser list of a) constructor, but indeed not after the class instance has been initialised.

Reference member variables are even more problematic beyond the lifetime challenges that both references and pointers have. Since references cannot be made to point to other objects nor default initialised, such member necessarily makes the class non-"regular" i.e. the class won't behave similar ways as fundamental types do. This makes such classes less intuitive to use.

TL;DR:

- Java idioms don't work in C++.
- Java references are very different from C++ references.
- If you think that you need a reference member, then take a step back and consider another idea. First thing to consider: Instead of referring to an object stored elsewhere, could the object be stored inside the class? Is the class needed in the first place?

Comment: Either that or some managed pointer like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` as mentioned by @user17732522, as it's often bad to think of C++ pointers like Java references. That and awareness of what the semantics should be (owning, non-owning, etc).

Comment: *Java idioms* ***don't*** *work in C++.* -- that feels a bit too strong

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Well, it's either that or "Java idioms work 5 days a week in C++"